# How to check if user is online by grabbing the last online from the database?

Tags: php

This is what I have, but for some reason it's giving me an error.
How could I do this?

```
function calc_online_users()
{
    global $pdo;
    $c = 0;
    $till = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime("-5 minutes"));
    $query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM members');
    while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        if($result['uLastLogin'] > $till)
        {
            $c++;
        }
    }
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's not really an error. It isn't calculating it correctly.
Is there like a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you write "it's giving me an error" and then you say there is no error? Are you trying to make this more interesting by feeding us incorrect information? Please edit your question and be clear about what happens and what you expect to happen instead. Till then I vote for closing this question as with conflicting information it's unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use SQL to count items and just fetch:

```
$minutes=5;
$c=$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM members WHERE uLastLogin > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $minutes MINUTE)")->fetchColumn();
```